# How to user where in Set<> Method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have an `UnitOfWork` interface like this :

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{     
   //some other methods
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

and implement it like this:

```
public class StoreContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

and I use `Set` methods I service layer like this :

```
public class BrandService : IBrandService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IDbSet<Brand> _brands;

    public BrandService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
            _uow = uow;
            _brands = _uow.Set<Brand>();
    }
}
```

I want use where in service layer after set method like this :

```
_brands = _uow.Set<Brand>().Where(row=>row.IsActive == true);
```

but it returns an error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet'

How can I do it ?

I searched on google but cant find similar question.

I used this code :

```
 _uow = uow;
 _brands = _uow.Set<Brand>();

 var data = _uow.Set<Brand>().Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false);
 _brands = (IDbSet<Brand>)data.ToList();
```

but it returns `buildPlan.Cs` not found

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign `IQueryable` to `IDbSet`. Change your declaration to

```
private IQueryable<Brand> _brands;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want work with Idbset<T> , I dont want use `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`

Comment: @UthmanRahimi Unfortunately, there is no way to assign the query result to `dbset`. What is the sense of doing something like this: `_brands = _uow.Set<Brand>().Where(row=>row.IsActive == true); _brands.Add(new Brand() {...})`? You can't add the entity to the query.

Comment: I Add an extention Method and use it like `_brands.Active().OrderBy(row => row.Code)` , whats do you think of ?

Comment: @UthmanRahimi Yes, that's a good idea. But the result of `Active()` still will be `IQueryable`, not `IDbSet`.

Answer (score 0):

romanoza tahnks for your answer. 
If I filter data in `Service Constructor` for All rows where `IsActive` equals `True`  ,I cant show user all rows where `IsActive  =false` and to do this I craete An extiontion methods Like this :

```
 public static IQueryable<TEntity> ACtive<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set) where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return set.Where(row=>row.IsActive==true);
    }
```

and everywhere I need , I just call `Active` Method Like this :

```
   public async Task<Brand> GetAsync(Guid brandId)
    {
        return await _brands.Active().Where(row => row.Id == brandId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Brand>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _brands.Active().ToListAsync();
    }
```

I thinks this is  better . 
*what your opinion?*

Comment: Yes, extension `IQueryable<TEntity> Active<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set)` is a good idea.